# Color top section of Android CardView while keeping rounded corners

Tags: android, xml, material-design

So I feel like I'm missing something, but I just cant seem to figure this out. So I want to make a small strip of color on the top of my CardView, but if I use a frame layout, or any kind of layout and set the background color, it covers up the rounded corners of the CardView. Here is some code and a screenshot of the issue. Thank you ahead of time!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:clipChildren="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menuCardImage"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuCardImage"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuCardName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: issue image]

Edit:
Turns out it was just a display issue in android studio. When I installed the app it worked correctly.

Comment: try android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"  on card view, or create a shape drawable with corner radius same as cardview corner-radius and set it as bg of any view

Comment: Is this happening on pre-Lollipop only?

Answer (score 3):

rather than setting color as background use this drawable to set background.

Create `top_strip.xml` in `drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFffffff"/>
</shape>
```

set the radius equal to that of card corner radius and change color as required. It will work

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set ***CardView*** color now.

```
color = ContextCompat.getColor(cardView.getContext(), R.color.white);
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

This is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try using `app:cardBackgroudColor` and `CardView.setCardBackgroundColor`. This worked out for me.